# How do I turn off the sound signal?

Tags: ndepend

When an error occurs,`NDepend` beeps.
When the project has errors.
How do I turn off the sound signal?

---

### Update-1

I use:

- Visual **NDepend**.

The event at which the **sound signal** appeared:

- I performed the `close project` action.
  `File -> Close Project.`
  There was some kind of malfunction in the project.
  Therefore, a beep sounded and a dialog box appeared.
  Window content: Probably suggested saving something.

### Update-2

Created the `NDepend` project.
Added a project for analysis.
Clicked: File -> Close Project.
`NDepend` - performed a beep and displayed a window with a suggestion to save the project `NDepend`.

Comment: Could you please describe when this beep occurs exactly? When running VisualNDepend? NDepend.Console? VS extension? What do you mean by project has error? Which NDepend version are you using? You can come back to us at support at ndepend dot com  thanks

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam See **Update-1**.

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam See **Update-2**.

Comment: Ok thanks, we'll add a setting to let the user discard any beep from the product

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam I think you need to formalize your comment as an answer. I will mark your answer as a ready solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since NDepend v2022.2.1 released 10th of November 2022 there is a new Miscellaneous option panel that contains the disable sound required setting:

[image: NDepend options for sound settings]